# Recording history for a track in a video

Tags: algorithm, time, video-tracking

This is a bit of a logical question

I am tracking an object in a video running at N fps. In a practical system, the frames don't have the exact gap and may even have frame drops

-> I am also provided with timestamp with every frame.
-> I start my track at frame X and end at Frame Y

I have divided my video into grids (spatially) and at each instance, I place the object into one of the grids

Now the simplest case of this issue is as follows,
Suppose the object was identified in just 1 frame, what should be the duration for that track?

Options: 
1. Exclusive duration computation

Duration = end time - start time = 0 for this instance

2. Inclusive duration computation

Duration = end time - start time + 1 = 1* for this instance 
*let us assume we have the information in milliseconds for now

3. Add frame gap. Since we know the FPS, we can compute 1/N to be the frame gap

Duration = end time - start time + 1/N

4. Add average time spent in a grid by computing speed of the person. I am not sure how to compute this since, it depends on previous 3 definitions of duration
5. Any other metric I can take?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If an object appears at frame X, and disappears at X+1, `end time` shall be the time of frame X+1, not frame X. Now, duration is obviously computed as `end time` - `start time` which in this case will be frame gap.

Comment: I mean I have recorded the first and last seen. In this case, It appears in 1 frame exactly. so by your logic, the duration is 0 since end time = start time

Comment: But I get what you are saying. Thing is, I can't record when the tracker isn't in the grid no? So I need to record the time before